# REACT, form submit after preventDefault not working until submit button is clicked a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    import React , {useState } from "react";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {push,ref} from "firebase/database";
import db from "./firebase";


function App() {
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");
  const [hes, setHes] = useState("");
  const [visa, setVisa] = useState("");
  const [islem , setIslem] = useState("");
  
  const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    setAge(event.target[0].value);
    setHes(event.target[1].value);
    setVisa(event.target[2].value);
    push(ref(db,"info"),{
      age: age,
      hes: hes,
      visa : visa,
      islem : islem
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
    <Form onSubmit={
      handleSubmit
    }>
    <Form.Group   className="mb-3 mx-3" >
      <Form.Label>AGE</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control name="age" type="text" placeholder="AGE: " />
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group  className="mb-3 mx-3" >
      <Form.Label>HES</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control  name="hes" type="text" placeholder="Hes CODE: " />
      
    </Form.Group>
    <Form.Group  className="mb-3 mx-3" >
      <Form.Label>VISA</Form.Label>
      <Form.Control  name="visa" type="text" placeholder="Visa: " />
    </Form.Group>
  
    <div className="d-grid gap-2">
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        setIslem("NC")
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      New Customer
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("NCC");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      New Cards
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("FI");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      For information
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("WDM");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Withdraw / Deposit Money
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("IO");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Insurance Operations
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("RO");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Retirement Operations
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {(e) =>{
        setIslem("PT")  
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Paying Fines / Taxes / Debt
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("SME");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      SME Operations
      </Button>
      <Button onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("INO");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Investment Operations
      </Button>
      <Button  onClick = {() =>{
        
        setIslem("MM");
      }}variant="secondary" type="submit" size="lg">
      Money Management
      </Button>
  </div>
    
  </Form>
  
  </div>
  
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my code, database writing data after only 2nd submission and it is writing old data. I want to write data in first submission.
For example:
in first submission my data is : age = 15,
in second submission my data is : age = 16,

In database it is written like: [age = "" , age = "15"]. It is coming always 1 step behind. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you update the states at the time of modification and not at the time of submission, anyway, to fix the problem you have I suggest you send the parameters of the form instead of the states since React will not change the value of these until the next render.

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    setAge(event.target[0].value);
    setHes(event.target[1].value);
    setVisa(event.target[2].value);
    push(ref(db,"info"),{
      age: event.target[0].value,
      hes: event.target[1].value,
      visa : event.target[2].value,
      islem : islem
    })
  }
```

In this case however the state variables (setAge, setHes, setVisa) are unnecessary I would say